# How to validate an image in ranorex

Tags: ranorex

I am testing my software that is used to insert images by dragging and dropping just like in auto-cad .
So when I insert an image by dragging and dropping , I want to validate the image by comparing it with a stored image to check if the specific image is inserted or not.
Any suggestion will help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add a lot more information. Are you trying to compare 2 image files or are you trying to compare images themselves eg. are the images being displayed in the AUT. But yeah 2 guidelines: if you are comparing image (or presented image in the application) then you could validate using Ranorex image comparison features. But if you have 2 image files it's a good idea to compare the file data eg. size, format, parameters etc. But again please be more precise when giving information for your needs.

Comment: Actually the thing is, I have given a task which is as follows:
1) Open the application.
2) drag and drop an image in the drawing area(just like we do in auto cad )
3) Now I have to test that the image that I dragged and dropped is successfully inserted or not.
For that I am trying to compare the image that I inserted with a screenshot of the same image that I already took using snipping tool.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.
I have to make the element available in repository so that it can be used for validation.
After adding the element in the repository, the screenshot of that element will be available to compare with your searched image.